# MySql: Hide certain tables from certain users

Tags: mysql

I want to hide certain tables (some definition tables) in the database from certain users. There is this **mysql.tables_priv** table which is empty. Should I insert something in that table to make it happen and what should be the value of 'table_priv' column?

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into the SQL GRANT command. With GRANT, you can assign privileges to users like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table TO user;
```

Comment: But **mysql.tables_priv** table is empty; Does that mean every user has all rights on every table?
Also, my concern is to 'Revoke' the right of view/editing a table.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a MySQL expert, I guess Google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the tables_priv is empty, i believe it means no privileges has been granted for that database table.  You can do a quick test and grant select on database.table_name to user
and see if a row appears in that table.  But normally your grants on tables appear in that table.

Comment: Yeah, I granted some roles to a table and those entries appear in the **tables_priv**. Otherwise there's nothing in that table. And it seems all users have all rights on all tables!?